# I can't send a message to a specific user in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a system that sends a user a message when a command is called. But whenever I try, it says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined.`

Here is the code I am using.

```js
 client.users.cache.get("220683253789163520").send("Test")
```

I am using discord version 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the user is not cached, before you need to fetch the user with [`<Client>.users.fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch) method.

Example for your case:

```
await client.users.fetch('220683253789163520');
client.users.cache.get('220683253789163520').send('Test');
```

Comment: I am now getting the error `DiscordAPIError: 404: Not Found`

Comment: Now it should works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Client.users.fetch()` to get directly from the API

```js
const user = await client.users.fetch("220683253789163520")
await user.send("Test")
```